# Why can't you instantiate a trait in scala?

Tags: scala

Why can't I instantiate a trait?  The compiler complains that the trait is abstract, but I don't have any abstract method or field in the trait.

```
scala> trait A
scala> new A
<console>:9: error: trait A is abstract; cannot be instantiated
              new A
              ^
```

Comment: To initialize traits, you have to `new A {}`.

Comment: I know we can use new A{}, but why new A failed? just like new a class?

Comment: It's just a syntactical rule. Trait initialize room requires it because you're making a new anonymous instance.

Comment: The answer below is clear and concise.

Answer (score 11):

It fails because traits are always abstract by definition, like Java interfaces.

When you write `new A {}` it means "create an anonymous class extending `A` and create an instance of it". This anonymous class is, of course, not abstract, so this works.